# Reorganizing a vector in c++

Tags: c++, vector, fftw

I'd like to preface this question with the fact that I am very inexperienced when it comes to coding, so the solution to this problem could be much easier than what I have been trying. I have a vector 'phas' defined as `vector<float> phase;` that has 7987200 elements and I want to rearrange this vector into 133120 vectors of 60 elements (called line2 defined as `vector<long double> line2;`). Each vector of 60 should then be placed one after the other in a vector of vectors 'RFlines2' defined as `vector< vector<long double> > RFlines2;`and `RFlines2.resize(7987200);`. I want to fill each of the 60 element vectors with elements of 'phas' separated by 128. for example, the first vector of 60 elements would be filled with phas[0], phas[128], phas[256], ... phas[7680]. The second vector of 60 would then be filled with phas[1], phas[129], phas[257], ... phas[7681],...etc. My current code is as follows:

```
    for(int x = 0; x<133120; x++){
        if((x == 128 || x == 7680+128 || x == (7680*a)+128)){
            x = 7680*a;
            a = a + 1;
        }
        int j = x;
        for(int i = 0; i<60;i++){
            line2.pushback(i);
            line2[i] = phas[j];
            j = j + 128;
        }
        cout<<"This is x: "<<x<<endl;
        RFlines2[x] = line2;
        line2.clear();
        }
```

however, after 128 iterations of the outter loop (128 vectors of 60 have been created and 7680 elements from phas have been used), I would need the x value to jump to 7680 to avoid putting elements from phas that have already been used into the next vector of 60 since when x = 128 the first element of the next vector of 60 would be phase[128], which was already used as the 2nd element of the first vector of 60. And then after another 128 x iterations, I would need the x value to jump to 15,360 and so on. The code above is my latest attempt, but when I try to do the fftw on each vector of 60 in RFlines2 as follows:

```
    int c = 0;
   for(int x = 0; x < 133120; x++){
    //cout<<x<<endl;

   fftw_plan p2;

   inter = (fftw_complex*) fftw_malloc(sizeof(fftw_complex) * W);
   outter = (fftw_complex*) fftw_malloc(sizeof(fftw_complex) * W);

    /* cast elements in line to type fftw_complex */
    for (int i = 0; i <60; i++) {
    //cout<<i<<endl;
    //inter[i][0] = phas[i];
    //inter[x][0] = zlines[x]; 
    inter[i][0] = RFlines2[x][i];
    inter[i][1] = 0;
  }

    p2 = fftw_plan_dft_1d(60, inter, outter, FFTW_FORWARD, FFTW_ESTIMATE);
    fftw_execute(p2);
    //inter[x][0].clear();
    for(int u = 0; u<60;u++){
        if(u == 0){
        cout<<' '<<outter[0][0]<<' '<<c++<<endl;
        }
    }
    fftw_free(inter);
    fftw_free(outter);
    fftw_destroy_plan((p2));
   }
```

the program crashes after displaying outer[0][0] 128 times. Any ideas how to fix this? Also, let me know if anything that I said doesn't make sense and I'll try to clarify. Thanks in advance!

-Mike

Comment: "has 7987200 elements and I want to rearrange this vector into 133120 vectors of 60 elements" - so why exactly is your target for this monstrosity,  the vector of vectors `RFlines2`, being sized to 7987200 via `RFlines2.resize(7987200);`,  if you only need 133120?

Comment: because, it is supposed to have 133120 vectors of 60 elements, which means it would need room for 7987200 elements? Or is that not how it works?

Comment: @user3798269: That's not how it works. When you resize a vector of vectors, you set the *number of inner vectors*, not the total number of elements in the vector of vectors. Each internal vector probably needs re-sizing as well.

Comment: First impressions: 1) you should try this with much smaller data sets, before attempting it with sets too big to print out and check by eye, 2) you seem to be mixing vectors and arrays in a way that I find quite unsettling (and if you know how to handle vectors you have no reason to mess around with arrays) 3) you are doing much more allocating and freeing than is necessary.

Comment: hahah okay, wow! I'll try to make my code a little more efficient by fixing the memory allocation and freeing thing and the resizing of the vectors...I'm not so sure about the whole vectors/arrays thing though and why you find it "unsettling" (thank you for describing it that way, I'm not offended nor am I being sarcastic when I say that I got a good laugh out of it because I knew by code was bad it was just funny to hear you describe it that way.) I guess the fact that I thought that I was only using vectors goes a long way in telling you just how basic my coding knowledge is.

Comment: I will try to work on my code and post an update tomorrow night if I still am having trouble, thanks everyone for your suggestions/comments!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why your code crashes, because I can't see the whole code here. But I'm going to suggest a way to scatter your data and manage your vectors.

(There is an important caveat though: you should not be using vectors (at least not vectors of vectors) for this task; you are better off using 1D vectors and managing the 2D indexing yourself. But this is a performance thing, and does not impact correctness.)

This is how I suggest you fill your `RFLines2`: (I have not tried this code, so it may not work.)

```
// first, build the memory for RFLines2...
vector<vector<long double>> RFLines2 (133120, vector<long double>(60));

// assuming a "phase" vector...
for (unsigned i = 0; i < 7987200; ++i)
{
    unsigned const row = (i / (128 * 60)) * 128 + (i % (128 * 60)) % 128;
    unsigned const col = (i % (128 * 60)) / 128;
    RFLines[row][col] = phase[i];
}
```

You won't need the `line2` intermediate this way.

The rest of the code "***should***" work. (BTW, I don't understand the inner `for` loop on `u` *at all*. What were you trying to do there?)

Comment: `(i % (128 * 60)) % 128` can be simplified to `i % 128`.

Comment: @Jarod42: Mathematically speaking that's true, but not logically. I want the written calculation to reflect the mental process of arriving at the formula.

Comment: That worked like a charm @yzt! Why is it necessary to make `i` unsigned and `row`/`col` unsigned const?

Comment: The whole u loop thing was to check the first value from the fttw on each of the vectors of 60 (it was being compared to a 3D matrix in matlab where each element in the y-dimension corresponded to the first element from the fftw of the 60 element vectors). The loop was there to count using `c` to make sure that I was getting the correct number of elements. Looking back, the loop was not necessary.

Comment: @user3798269: Neither is strictly necessary. But these are indices into vectors (or arrays) and that is an unsigned value (most of the time.) Also, if you actually want to compare them with a vector's `.size()` (in the loop condition or in an `assert()` or something,) you'll get a warning if your indices are not unsigned. The `const`ness is just the Right Thing. When something is constant, why not declare it as so?!